# Ambigous column name error

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, select

I have an issue with select command from 2 tables.

So I have table1 with:

```
table1_id = int pk;    
table1_name;   
table1_surname;   
table1_age;    
table1_address;   
table1_city;
```

And table2 with:

```
table2_id int pk   
table1_id int fk references table1.table1_id;   
table3_id;  
table2_description;
```

When I write the following select statement, I get ambigous column name table1.table1_name error:

```
SELECT table2.table2_id, table2.table1_id, table1.table1_name, table2.table2_description
from table1,
     table2 inner join
     table1
     on table2.table1_id = table1.table1_id;
```

Honestly I do not understand what is wrong about it?

Comment: "Honestly I do not understand what is wrong about it?" Try Google or Stackoverflow search iam sure other poeple had have this error before..

Comment: From table and join table1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you have problem in below line

```
from table1, table2
```

In the above code you are using a `CROSS JOIN` between `table2` and `table1` which is not required in your case.

Change your query like following.

```
SELECT table2.table2_id, table2.table1_id, table1.table1_name, table2.table2_description 
from  table2 
 inner join table1 on table2.table1_id = table1.table1_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `table1,` just after `from` ( mixed old type "comma" and modern join syntaxes)

Use like the following :

```
SELECT t2.table2_id, t2.table1_id, t1.table1_name, t2.table2_description 
  FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON ( t2.table1_id = t1.table1_id ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
select t2.table2_id, t2.table1_id, t1.table1_name, t2.table2_description
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2 
     on t2.table1_id = t1.table1_id;
```

The problem with your query is that you have two references to `table1` because of the comma.  You have mentioned the table  twice.  Hence, when you reference the column, the engine doesn't know what you are referring to.  Your version is equivalent to:

```
from table1 cross join
     table2 join
     table1
     on table2.table1_id = table1.table1_id
```

`table1` appears twice, so any reference to it is ambiguous.

You will notice that I also added table aliases to the query.  Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.