# how to use 'inner join' and 'order by' in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use inner join and order in my query in php page.
My query :

```
select 
    * 
from 
    table1 
inner join 
    table1category 
    on table1.table1category_id = table1category.id
order by updateDate desc;
```

'updateDate' is for table1 => error : Column 'updateDate' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: The error message says it all. You need to specify which updateDate to order by. E.g. try `order by table1.updateDate desc`.

Comment: you need to add table_name, like `order by table1.updateDate`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambigous column name error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316080/ambigous-column-name-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when there is same column in two table then you've to specify the table name with that columns

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table1category
  ON table1.table1category_id = table1category.id
ORDER BY table1.updateDate DESC;
```

Comment: select table1.rowid

Answer (score 7):

**Column 'updateDate' in order clause is ambiguous**

Means that updateDate exists in both tables you are trying to use.
If you want to order using this field, you have to specify from which table you want it to be ordered by.

For example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table1category
  ON table1.table1category_id = table1category.id
ORDER BY table1.updateDate DESC;
```

Also, consider that using `*` on a **SELECT** with **JOINS** will get all the columns from all the included tables.

Comment: It's weird to see that every one else is duplicating the same after you answered.

Comment: well... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: you have to specify every field you want to the SELECT instead of *, this also improve the performance of the query.

Answer (score 4):

Its because `updateDate` exists in both tables- table1 and table1category

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN table1category tc
  ON t.table1category_id = tc.id
ORDER BY t.updateDate DESC;
```

Comment: By specifically naming the columns that you need to use in your select or simply use alias naming to differentiate between the two

Answer (score 2):

You have to say which table to use for this field (presents in both tables):

```
select *
from table1
inner join table1category on table1.table1category_id = table1category.id
order by XXX.updateDate desc;
```

Replace XXX by table1 or table1category.

You can set aliases on tables too, like:

```
select *
from table1 as myalias1
inner join table1category as myalias2 on table1.table1category_id = table1category.id
order by XXX.updateDate desc;
```

Then replace XXX by myalias1 or 2.

You can do the same for selecting datas (for example):

```
SELECT table1.id AS id, table2.id AS categoryId
```

Answer (score 2):

Column `updateDate` in order clause is ambiguous

Try This

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1category t2
  ON t1.table1category_id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.updateDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that using aliases often makes joins easier

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1 AS alias1
INNER JOIN table1category AS alias2
  ON alias1.table1category_id = alias2.id
ORDER BY alias1.updateDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing table name

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table1category
  ON table1.table1category_id = table1category.id
ORDER BY table1.updateDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, table1.updateDate as "Table1 Update Date"
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table1category ON table1.table1category_id = table1category.id
ORDER BY table1.updateDate DESC;
```

or you can keep alias in ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT *, table1.updateDate as "Table1 Update Date"
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table1category ON table1.table1category_id = table1category.id
ORDER BY "Table1 Update Date" DESC;
```

**Note**
Use keywords always in UPPER case
Better to use alias in SELECT CLAUSE for better understanding, otherwise it will add 1 to **updateDate**  i.e. **updateDate1**.
Always use alias for same column names
Don't use all columns i.e. * , fetch only required columns

Answer (score 0):

select 
    * 
from 
    table1 T
inner join 
    table1category C
    on T.table1category_id = C.id
order by T.updateDate desc;